# .net and jirasoapservice

Tags: c#, .net, soap, jira

How I can create unassigned issue? By default all issue assigned for user who created it .
I try using new user but it don't work:

```
JiraService.RemoteUser reporter = _jiraSoapService.getUser(_token, _userName);
JiraService.RemoteUser assignee = new JiraService.RemoteUser();
issue.reporter = reporter.name; 
issue.assignee = assignee.name;       
JiraService.RemoteIssue returnedIssue = _jiraSoapService.createIssue(_token, issue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up Jira so that it allows unassigned issue. Go to the General Configuration page of the Administration section and turn the 'Allow Unassigned Issues' flag on. Make sure to edit the project and change the "Default Assignee:" to be "Unassigned." Otherwise, the default assignee will continue to be whoever was originally assigned to the project.

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+JIRA+Options

Comment: I know how change this parameter from config but I need use SOAP.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to do using SOAP.

Comment: Provide a valid assignee when you call createIssue. A reporter is also needed.